# Can I store a clients website within my website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I'm working on a clients pre-existing web site. I would like to take the solution they sent me and host it within my web site so that I can make changes to it and the client can see them without modifying their current live version without their approval.

It would be nice to store on a sub domain. How do I contain the web site within a folder so that it doesn't conflict with my web.config and other files?

Comment: Yo dawg I put a website withing your website so you can....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you are talking about is taking their files and hosting them on a domain of your choice ... this is generally deemed a Dev Site. Nothing fancy here, just create a IIS directory or application for the client's version of software on your server machine and map your domain to it via DNS settings.

Here is an article on creating sub domains

http://forums.asp.net/t/874598.aspx